# how to electrically charge object like comb

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electrons

I know we can electrically charge comb my rubbing against hair which in turn will attract paper pieces. But is there way to charge object e.g. comb automatically. e.g. using battery or something. So when I turn on switch it will charge. I was trying to find working example or video.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_de_Graaff_generator